# Using NSMutableArray for Map Annotations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I have filled a NSMutablearray with Objects from my XML praser. I now what to use that to populate for my Map Annotations. I have this Array working for my Table which brings the objects into the cell, but I want to use the same NSMutablearray for my map.

```
//currentBranch is filled with my Objects
Mapdets *currentBranch = [[xmlParser branch]];



[mapview setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapview setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapview setScrollEnabled:YES];

MKCoordinateRegion region = {{0.0, 0.0}, {0.0,0.0 }};
region.center.latitude = -33.86434888;
region.center.longitude = 151.2090236;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.10f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.10f;
[mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];




 //Annotation code will go here. Need help with that.
```

Ok So this is where i'm at. I have that array filled with objects that is filled with Title, subtile, Latitude, Longitude, i want to basically xpolde that array and use the elements.

Thanks for the help.

My array is filled as such if i run NSLog(@"%@", currentBranch);

```
2013-02-28 07:53:53.537 SAMPLE[13642:207] (
    "<Mapdets: 0x754d3b0>",
    "<Mapdets: 0x754d5c0>",
    "<Mapdets: 0x754d710>"
)
```

And in my XMLpraser file i fill it like this.

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{
    if (isStatues) 
    {
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"title"]) 
        {
            currentBranch.title = currentNodeContent;


        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"street_address"]) 
        {
            currentBranch.subtitle = currentNodeContent;
        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"lng"]) 
        {
            currentBranch.lng = currentNodeContent;
        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"lat"]) 
        {
            currentBranch.lat = currentNodeContent;
        }
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"branch"]) 
    {
        [self.branch addObject:currentBranch];
        currentBranch = nil;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
```

This is all working, I just want to now use this NSMutablearray in another class for my map.

Comment: may be this can be a help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711086/adding-multiple-annotations-to-iphone-mapview-is-slow

Comment: can you show us your array content???? You must be having dictionaries in that array.

Comment: I added some revised code to how i fill the array. thanks

Comment: does these values in ur NSLog looks like ur values???? i guess you first need to first parse your xml properly.

Comment: @Smriti  if i do this, i can see each value if i change the integer. NSInteger index = 1;
     Mapdets *currentBranch = [[xmlParser branch] objectAtIndex:index]; NSString *title = currentBranch.title;

Comment: One more note, this is a multi array. So in here is 3-Objects and then each object has a array of items.

Comment: i guess you should follow above link provided by @rptwsthi, that's explain everything about adding annotation.

Comment: Take Branch as (NSMutableArray) in Appdelegate  and  [appdelegate.branch addObject:currentBranch];...now u can use this array any where in u r App.

Comment: Use NSUserDefault , follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509999/i-have-nsstring-value-in-addviewcontroller-and-i-want-to-display-this-value-in-u/13619879#13619879

Answer (score 1):

Take Branch(`NSMutableArray`) in Appdelegate and

In u r .h file take AppDelegate reference

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate;
```

and in .m file   In ViewDidLoad Method write this below line

```
appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

and add this line `[appdelegate.branch addObject:currentBranch]`; instead of  `[self.branch addObject:currentBranch]`;

...now u can use this appdelegate.branch(Array) any where in u r App.